# Is it possible to have threads spawned under Unity3D runtime leveraging multi core systems?

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, parallel-processing, mono

Phrasing it differently: Can multithreading under Unity's Mono result in parallelism?

Research (based on Samsung Galaxy S5 and iPhone4S profiling):

I tried spawning Unity3D-agnostic threads in C# that carry out some heavier calculations hoping for a parallel execution and performance improvement. I reduced sync operations as much as I could, but I saw no frame rate improvement at all which makes me think everything's still executed on one core. And that's perfectly fine on it's own - after all multi-threading doesn't need to result in parallelism.

But can it result in parallel execution (multi core execution)?

I would love to hear an answer like:

1. Yes, I am completely positive that under XYZ circumstances your thread can be executed on a separate core. If that's the case:

   - Can you point to any example?
   - How would you measure if other cores are doing relevant work on mobile devices?
   - Is there a setting of any kind to enable parallelism? For example defining number of cores that can be used when available (platform specific deployment)

or

2. No. You can have multi-threading but no parallelism because XYZ constrains you to multi-threaded but single-core execution.

Answers that don't help:

1. Yes it's perfectly fine to have Unity agnostic threads executed concurrently - Yup I know, I managed to leverage that, but the question is about parallelism's viability not multi-threading.
2. Unity API is not thread safe, be careful - Yup, that's true, thank you.
3. Please post an example of how you carried out your research - Maybe you are right and I am missing something, but I think that the main question is a yes/no question. Given strong motivation i am perfectly happy with that sort of answer. I believe example would be a bit involved and would obscure the main question, so for now I would prefer not to post examples.
4. You can find examples of code written with parallelism in mind on MSDN - that's true, however most of features supporting parallelism were introduced in .NET 4.0, we are talking about Mono 2.0 and there may be some additional platform specific constraints.

Comment: Sure, you can use threads in combination with Unity. As to what the exact problem is you're facing, we're going to need more information.

Comment: Question is if threads under unity runtime can be executed in parallel or is that somehow constrained? I am not asking if one can use threads, that i already do.

Comment: Can you add a small code example where and how you spin a managed thread in relation to your Unity3D code?

Comment: yes you can, but be careful that mostly every scripting API is meant to be called from the main thread. So if you threads need to use them, it could be a problem.

Comment: @Heisenbug Do you mean, it's perfectly possible to have parallel execution? If yes - is there any explicit effort needed on top regular multithreading? Can you point to any example of observable parallelism?

Comment: Yes it's possible. You can use thread as usual in C# (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). It's also plenty of examples, just google for unity3d, c#, thread and can see several examples. The main drawback, is that is not safe calling many API from an arbitrary thread (es. modify a transform) so you should be careful.